# Проблема со Splitter при использовании WS_EX_COMPOSITED в родительском окне

Tags: c#

В TabControl для того, чтобы избавиться от мерцания дочерних окон

при изменении размеров формы, устанавливаю стиль [WS_EX_COMPOSITED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx)

Но при этом перестает отрисовываться Splitter при перетягивании.

Как это можно решить?

Спасибо.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// H_TODO:  Избавляюсь от flickering в дочерних окнах. Но при этом возникает проблема с отрисовкой Splitter при перемещении
    /// </summary>
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= User32.WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А где находится Splitter?

Comment: На нескольких уровнях ниже TabControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже без хака не обойтись.

Учитывая что флаг нужен только для ресайза, то просто в начале ресайза формы устанавливаем флаг WS_EX_COMPOSITED и после ресайза - снимаем.

```
    private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -16;
    private const int WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
```